# High current motor control

Tags: mosfet, motor, integrated-circuit, dc-motor, h-bridge

When designing for relatively high currents, e.g. 6-10A, what is the standard practice for motor control? Is it to construct an H-bridge out of discrete components, to use integrated half bridges, or to use integrated H-bridges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done all three, I can safely say "it depends".

You need to evaluate all three approaches, with your requirements in mind. You don't mention any of your requirements. Are you thinking steppers? brushed? brushless?

6 to 10 amps is not that high, so there is no real difficulty there. The voltage is more of an issue than the current. A 20 volt / 10 amp motor driver is a piece of cake, a 50 volt / 10 amp driver is not as easy, and a 300 volt / 10 amp driver is downright difficult.

If you are not comfortable designing from scratch, then the more integrated the parts, the safer you are. But often the highly integrated solutions don't fit the need, unless the need is pretty generic. Discrete components will give you the lowest cost, if that's one of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I am more thinking about brushed DC motors at around 12V.

Comment: With only 12 volts, your main concern is being sure you fully turn on the FETs. P-channel FETs at the top can make it really simple if you are not running a closed current loop. You could easily do it with discrete parts. If you are running closed-loop, then I would recommend using a full H-bridge module that has the current-sense circuitry included.

Comment: So if running open-loop, the high-side FETs should be P-channel, and the low-side FETs should be N-channel? Is that right?

Comment: That would be the simplest topology. The only drawback is that a P-channel FET has higher ON resistance, so it generates more heat inside the FET. If you're running closed-loop, and therefore pulse-width-modulating, you could PWM the high side to partially mitigate the higher resistance. The P-channel FETs would be ON less than the N-channel FETs on the low side, and barely ON at all when the current demand is low.